# Canvas in Firefox and Chrome give different RGB Values

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, canvas

I'm running following code in both Chrome and Firefox up-to-date versions.

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');       
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) 
    {
        var fileCount=fileInput.files.length;   
        for(var i=0;i<fileCount;i++)
        {
            var file = fileInput.files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) 
    {   
                    var screenshotImage = new Image();          
        screenshotImage.onload = function() 
        {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.id     = makeid(5);                      
            var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');                    
            canvas.width = this.width;
            canvas.height = this.height;
            canvasContext.drawImage(this,0,0,this.width, this.height);
                            var imgd = canvasContext.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            imagePxielData.push(imgd.data);                     
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
        screenshotImage.src = this.result;
    }   
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }           
    });
}

function readData()
{
    for(var i=0;i<imageCount;i++)
{
        var imgdata=imagePxielData[i];
        tmp=0;
        for (var j = 0, n = imgdata.length; j < n; j += 4) 
        {       
            var r = imgdata[j];
    var g = imgdata[j+1];
    var b = imgdata[j+2];

    if(tmp<100)
        console.log("r=>"+r+"g=>"+g+"b=>"+b);

            tmp++;
        }
    }
}
```

After running by uploading an image, the first 100 RGB values shows different values in Chrome and Firefox. Chrome shows the correct values and Firefox show different values(incorrect values).

Why is this showing different values ?
How can fix this to display correct RGB values in both Chrome and Firefox ?

Thank you.

Comment: How are they wrong? Does it look like a gamma/contrast issue? Scaling? Translation? Random? Also are the values after the first 100 correct or just untested?

Comment: When I print the RGB values, it show different in two browsers. The particular picture was created a c# program, and the pixel are created from 1 to 255 values for each RGB. In that case I can see the different values shows in the two different browsers. Chrome shows the correct values.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm asking in what way they are different.

Comment: numerical representation of the RGB values are different. After the image loaded, i run the read data function and try to get the same RGB values which I used in creating the Image. The Chrome give the correct value and Firefox is not.